# filtering out documents returned by $lookup in Mongo aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I am running this command:

`{ $lookup: { from: "views", localField: "checkedViews._id", foreignField: "id", as: "populatedViews" } },`

Unfortunately that is returning all `views` documents on each upload document, so when I run `$project` with

```
populatedViews: {
    $size: "$populatedViews"
},
```

It equals the total amount of views in the entire collection for each upload. Should I use `$filter` to only include documents that match via the `_id`, or how can I do that?

An example Video:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b5d09980348a3ec3541acc"),
    "checkedViews" : [ 
        ObjectId("59b5d0b280348a3ec3541acd"), 
        ObjectId("59b5d0bf80348a3ec3541ace"), 
        ObjectId("59b5d1dbd8f37d4ab797fa5c")
    ]
}
```

An example checkedView:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b5d0b280348a3ec3541acd"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-09-10T23:54:26.752Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-09-10T23:54:26.752Z"),
    "video" : ObjectId("59b5d09980348a3ec3541acc"),
    "validity" : "real",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
const oldUploads = await Video.aggregate([
      { $match:  {
        visibility: { $ne: 'removed' },
        'checkedViews.1' : { $exists: true }
      }},
      { $lookup: { from: "views", localField: "checkedViews._id", foreignField: "id", as: "populatedViews" } },
      { $project: {
        title: 1,
        checkedViews: 1,
        viewAmount: {
          $size: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$populatedViews",
              as: "view",
              cond: { $eq: ['$$view.id', '$checkedView.id'] }
            }
          }
        },
        populatedViews: {
          $size: "$populatedViews"
        },

      }
      },

      {
        $sort: { viewAmount: -1 }
      },
      { $skip: 1 },
      { $limit : 100 }
    ]);
```

Comment: What is your mongo version ? Not sure why lookup is not working for you as it should match ids properly. Can you please add the complete query to the post and add the sample document from each collection for your query ?

Comment: @Veeram updated, running 3.2.7

Comment: `$unwind` before the `$lookup` stage. `{ $unwind:"$checkedViews"}` and you will need a `$group` on `_id` and push `checkedViews` for a video at the end to get back to original shape.